# Resume make compilation process

Tags: makefile

I was compiling Qt5 for a embedded device on the device itself. This takes a long time since Qt sources are about 800mb and the embedded device isn't exactly fast.

Everything was running well, until a power shortage prevented the device from finishing `make`, therefore halting the compilation process.

Is there any way to resume from where it was left of?

Comment: If it's a well formed `makefile`, just type `make` again.

Comment: I was told `make -t` would resume it. I tried it but didn't work. Will this affect the process now?

Comment: You should give a big raspberry to whomever told you to use `make -t`.  That was singularly bad advice.  A quick read of the `make` man page would have warned you: _`-t`  Touch files (mark them up to date without  really changing them) instead of running their commands._  Clearly that's not going to do what you want.

Comment: @MadScientist Of course not. The person supposedly knew what was saying, so I took he's word and didn't checked on the docs `man make`. But I guess we all make mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a well-formed `makefile`, simply re-running `make` should allow you to resume the process.

The `make -t` command mentioned (assuming gnu make) simply touches the files (updates the timestamps) and doesn't actually perform the actions in the `makefile` so at this point, you'll probably have to start over.

Also rather than building on the slow target, consider setting up a cross-compiler and build system.  It's often a lot of work initially, but pays considerable dividends over time.  I would recommend [`crosstool-ng`](http://crosstool-ng.org/) as one of the least painful ways of setting up such an environment.

Comment: I setup the cross compilation and we are good. Qt compiled and running apps. Thank you.

Comment: @FábioAntunes: I'm glad it worked for you. Please consider upvoting the answer if you found it helpful.